# can I return report data using 'requestforquery' in salesforce ios sdk?

Tags: ios, objective-c, rest, salesforce, soql

I am using the Salesforce Mobile SDK 2.0 to build a connected Salesforce Native iOS app, I would like to be able to run reports programatically using the SFRestRequest method (or some other method?), can you show code examples of how this might be done? Secondly, is it also possible to send filter parameters through to the report as well, such as account id? My code snippet in its current state:

```
SFRestRequest *request = [[SFRestAPI sharedInstance] requestForQuery:@"SELECT id, Image_Filename__c FROM product2 WHERE (Group__c !='Discontinued') ORDER BY name ASC"];
[[SFRestAPI sharedInstance] send:request delegate:self];
```

Comment: can anybody help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this answer, you will need to create some clone methods:

[answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/18241/how-to-return-the-report-results-from-a-soql-query-using-the-rest-api-in-salesfo)